# Retrieving a Single String Value Without Listening for Changes Using Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my current code, but it doesn't work.

I am trying to Retrieve a Single String Value (DATA) Without Listening for Changes Using Firebase Realtime Database

But whenever I run this code, I get email[0] as null.

And also the `Log.e("Email#1", "hello");` never pops up in my logcat giving me the feeling that it never actually enters the `addListenerForSingleValueEvent()`.

```
 username=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
     password=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);


    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
    final Button login=(Button)findViewById(R.id.loginbtn);
    final Firebase ref=new Firebase("//fir-learn-4991c.firebaseio.com/Users/Sriharsha/email");

    //assert login != null;
    assert login != null;
    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            login.setText("Loading...");

           final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            DatabaseReference dref=database.getReference("email");

            final String user=username.getText().toString();
            final String[] email = new String[1];
            dref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    Message post = dataSnapshot.getValue(Message.class);
                    Log.e("Email#1","hello yo");
                    //System.out.println(post);
                    //Map<String, Object> newPost = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                    email[0]=post.getEmail();

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
                }
            });
```

This is Class: Message :-

```
  public class Message {
    private  String email;
    public Message(){

    }
    public void message(String email)
    {
        this.email=email;
    }
    public String getEmail()
    {
        return email;
    }

 }
```

And this is my Firebase database:
[Firebase database picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X54X0.png)

Comment: your dref by default points to the root of the database. Try this: DatabaseReference dref=database.getReference(); and set listener like this: dref.child("Users").addListenerForSingleValueEvent

Answer (score 0):

Your listener is set on the reference `email` (which if it doesn't exist and therefore doesn't trigger the listener), while it appears your email string is actually stored at `Users/<username?>/email`. You may want to change `dref` accordingly.

Comment: So would you advice me to put it, because I have tried all the possible ways that you suggest above but still the program never enters the listener!!! I need help!! I am trying to get a users email.

Comment: I would recommend setting `dref = database.getReference("Users").child(user).child(email)` instead of what you currently have.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. Thank You Everybody. I just did not use a String Array and also created it in a different method to get the straight String value from firebase.

```
Firebase ref=new Firebase("//fir-learn-4991c.firebaseio.com/Users/"+user);
            Firebase ref1=ref.child("email");
            final String pass=password.getText().toString();
            //Log.e("dref",dref.toString());
            ref1.addValueEventListener(new com.firebase.client.ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    String post=dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                    Log.v("Email#1",post);
                    authentication(post,pass,user);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

                }
            });

            Log.e("Email",""+ email[0]);
            Log.e("Ref",""+ ref);

        }

    });
}
public void newActivity(String email, String pass, String user)
{

    Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, THSTheApp.class);
    intent.putExtra("email",email);
    intent.putExtra("UserName", user);
   intent.putExtra("Password", pass);// pass your values and retrieve them in the other Activity using keyName
    startActivity(intent);
}
public void x()
{
    Toast.makeText(Login.this, "There Was A Problem",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    username.setText("");
    password.setText("");

}
public void authentication(final String email1, final String pass,final String user)
{
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email1, pass).addOnCompleteListener(Login.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful())
            {
                newActivity(email1,pass,user);
            }
            else if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                x();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}